# How do I perform following integral or find out for what values of parameters $c,\phi$ it is positive and for what values it is negative?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, improper-integrals, indefinite-integrals

I would like to know when the sign of following expression changes
\begin{equation}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{i \left(e^{c | p| }+e^{2 | p|  \sin (\phi )}\right) e^{-| p|  (c+\sin (\phi ))+i p \cos (\phi )}}{p \left(e^{c | p| }+1\right)}\mathrm{d}p-2 i \tanh ^{-1}\left(1+\frac{2 i e^{i \phi }}{c}\right)+2 i  \tanh ^{-1}\left(1-\frac{2 i e^{-i \phi }}{c}\right)- \pi
\end{equation}

Here $c>0, 0<\phi<\frac{\pi}{2}$ and I am interested in the region $3c>2\sin\phi$ and $c<2\sin(\phi)$. Numerically, I see that the expression can take both positive and negative values in the parametric region I am interested in. I would love to be able to do the integral analytically and solve for the $c,\phi$ such that the above expression is positive or negative. If the analytical solution is not possible, what would be the way to find out the relation between $c$ and $\phi$ where the integral is negative and the region where it is positive.

I can empirically find that at $c=\sin(\phi)$ the sign changes. But I would like to get some analytic way to see it.

The integral can also be written as
\begin{equation}
\int_0^{\infty } -\frac{2 e^{-c p} \text{sech}\left(\frac{c p}{2}\right) \sin (p \cos (\phi )) \cosh \left(\frac{1}{2} p (c-2 \sin (\phi ))\right)}{p} \mathrm{d}p
\end{equation}

Which can further be simplified as the sum of these two integrals
$$-2\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{-p \sin (\phi )} \sin (p \cos (\phi ))}{p \left(e^{c p}+1\right)} \, dp-2\int_0^{\infty } \frac{e^{p \sin (\phi )-c p} \sin (p \cos (\phi ))}{p \left(e^{c p}+1\right)} \, dp$$
For context: It is one of the two integrals describing energy of particles in a quantum field theoretic model I am looking at. In the post [Any ideas on how to perform this integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4683397/any-ideas-on-how-to-perform-this-integral), one of the integrals was solved but looks like because of the denominator $\frac{1}{e^{c|p|}+1}$, I do not seem to be able to adapt this integral to the way the other one was solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original form of the integral does not converge due to a non-integrable singularity at $p=0$.

The other two forms assume that you're taking the Cauchy principal value of this integral, or, equivalently, taking the real part of the integral.

---

To evaluate the integral in its third form, all we need is the the Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin(bp)}{p(e^{cp}+1)} $, which can be expressed in terms of the [log gamma function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogGammaFunction.html).

I'll show how to find it.

Assume that $b \in \mathbb{R}$, $c>0$, and $a +c >0$.

The Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin(bp)}{e^{cp}+1}$ is

$ \begin{align}   \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ap}\sin(bp)}{e^{cp}+1} \, \mathrm dp   &= \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(a-ib)p}-e^{-(a+ib)p}}{e^{cp}+1} \, \mathrm dp \\ &= \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(a-ib+c)p}-e^{-(a+ib+c)p}}{1+e^{-cp}} \, \mathrm dp \\ &=  \frac{1}{2i}\int_{0}^{\infty} \left( e^{-(a-ib+c)p} - e^{-(a+ib+c)p}\right) \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  (-1)^{n}e^{-cnp}  \, \mathrm dp \\ &= \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \left( e^{-(a-ib+c+cn)p} -e^{-(a+ib+c+cn)p} \right)\\ &= \frac{1}{2i}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{n} \left( \frac{1}{a-ib+c+cn} - \frac{1}{a+ib+c+cn}\right)\\ &= \frac{1}{2ic} \left( \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\frac{a-ib}{c}+1+n} - \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n}}{\frac{a+ib}{c}+1+n}\right)\\ &\overset{(1)}{=} \small\frac{1}{4ic} \left(\psi \left(\frac{a-ib}{2c}+1 \right)- \psi \left(\frac{a-ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right) - \psi \left(\frac{a+ib}{2c}+1 \right) + \psi \left(\frac{a+ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\right). \end{align}$

Therefore, the Laplace transform of $\frac{\sin(bp)}{p(e^{cp}+1)} $ is $$ \begin{align} &\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-ap}\sin(bp)}{p(e^{cp}+1)} \, \mathrm dp \\ &\overset{(2)}{=} \small\frac{1}{4ic}\int_{a}^{\infty} \left(\psi \left(\frac{t-ib}{2c}+1 \right)- \psi \left(\frac{t-ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right) - \psi \left(\frac{t+ib}{2c}+1 \right) + \psi \left(\frac{t+ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) \, \mathrm dt  \\ &= \small  \frac{1}{2i} \left( \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t-ib}{2c}+1 \right) - \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t-ib}{2c}  \frac{1}{2} \right)- \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t+ib}{2c}+1 \right) + \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t+ib}{2c}+\frac{1}{2} \right)\right) \Bigg|^{\infty}_{a} \\ &\overset{(3)}{=} \small \frac{1}{2i} \left( -\log \Gamma \left(\frac{a-ib}{2c}+1 \right) + \log \Gamma \left(\frac{a-ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)+\log \Gamma \left(\frac{a+ib}{2c}+1 \right) -    \log \Gamma \left(\frac{a+ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) \\ &= \Im \left(\log \Gamma \left(\frac{a+ib}{2c} + 1  \right) - \log \Gamma \left(\frac{a+ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\right) . \end{align}$$

---

$(1)$ https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html (6)

$(2)$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Evaluating_improper_integrals

$(3)$ As $t \to +\infty$, $$\log \Gamma(t+ \alpha) - \log \Gamma(t+ \beta) = (\alpha - \beta) \log(t) + O \left(\frac{1}{t} \right).$$

Therefore, as $t \to +\infty$, $$\small \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t-ib}{2c}+1 \right) - \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t-ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)-\log \Gamma \left(\frac{t+ib}{2c}+1 \right) +   \log \Gamma \left(\frac{t+ib}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right) \sim O \left(\frac{1}{t} \right). $$

---

So for $c>0$, $0 < \theta < \pi/2$, and $2c - \sin (\phi) >0 $, we have

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-p \sin (\phi)} \sin (p \cos (\phi ))}{p \left(e^{c p}+1\right)} \, \mathrm dp = \Im \left(\log \Gamma \left(\frac{ie^{- i \phi}}{2c} +1 \right) - \log \Gamma \left(\frac{ie^{-i \phi}}{2c} + \frac{1}{2} \right)\right)$$ and

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-p (c - \sin (\phi))} \sin (p \cos (\phi ))}{p \left(e^{c p}+1\right)} \, \mathrm dp = \Im \left(\log \Gamma \left(\frac{ie^{i \phi}}{2c} +\frac{3}{2} \right) - \log \Gamma \left(\frac{ie^{i \phi}}{2c} + 1 \right)\right). $$